# Is there a shortcut for wrapping a variable with a cast that is inferred by the IDE?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Just wondering if there is a convenience shortcut/chord for this. The IDE obviously knows the return type.

This is specific to Objective-C in the IDE, it seems that the IDE has this functionality when I use swift.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Say I have a method that returns `UINavigationController *` and I've performed some stupid hierarchy walk and have done something like `[vc isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.class]` and going to type `return vc;` is going to give me an obvious warning. The IDE knows it's supposed to be cast to `UINavigationController *`. In Swift the IDE performs this functionality -- hence the question here for Objective-C.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Without seeing code, I can't provide a concrete answer.  `instancetype` might be your friend, but there might still be an explicit cast needed somewhere.  Details: https://nshipster.com/instancetype/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this is not an issue of type inference (the IDE is already aware of the type that I want to cast), it's not a code question. `Incompatible pointer types returning 'UIViewController *' from a function with result type 'UINavigationController *'` -- the IDE is aware I want to use `vc` as a `UINavigationController *`, and I've already done the reflection test.

Comment: The compiler isn't aware, though.   Reflection tests are purely runtime;  they don't influence the compiler's type checking at all.   Can you show your method, please?